# SQL update multiple rows with different values, without specifying unique key

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I need help building a SQL query which searches for an user_id (let's say user_id = 5), but this user_id has multiple row entries, but I need to update each row differently though.

I have an array with data which I want to assign to that user_id. Here is a table example:

```
id    user_id    amount    txn_id
1     5          10        foo_unique
2     5          5         bar_unique
3     7          15        xyz_unique
4     5          10        123_unique
```

My array would look something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 9
)
```

As you see I have three array values and three rows for user_id 5, now I want to add each value of that array, to the corresponding user_id (5). Note that I have an UNIQUE column named `txn_id`

After updating the table, it would look like this:

```
id    user_id    amount    txn_id
1     5          14        foo_unique
2     5          5         bar_unique
3     7          6         xyz_unique
4     5          9         123_unique
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Thanks.

P.S: I cannot use SQL CASE on this issue.

Comment: hm, is it really good to update "random" rows? Why is there no key for the target row?

Comment: Any specific reason why you can't use SQL CASE? That would help us understand the limitation.

Comment: Yes. The source code I am working on never ever included any CASE query, and I cannot be the first one to use it.

Comment: "I cannot be the first one to use it." You can't be serious!

Comment: @bfavaretto Weird, isn't it? But yes, it's not up to me. Since I'm not the main author of that script, I can't be first to add new stuff to it. Maybe there is some reason why they didn't add it... Like not every DBMS supports such queries.

Comment: Is this for some specific DBMS or it should work in "general" SQL (if there is such a thing)?

Comment: `UPDATE` statement has some differences between DBMSs (and many of them do not follow the SQL-standard.)

Comment: The query should work on every DBMS, I just used SQL for... no idea why...

Comment: There is probably no UPDATE statement (for this problem, it's not a simple one) that will work in every DBMS. So, what you ask, cannot be done.

Comment: What if I get the array to include the `id` as keys instead of the standard keys?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update **one** row with a value, you have to be able to have a **unique condition** for **that row**.

Without adding some extra field, or condition to uniquely identify a row, you are out of luck.

Comment: There is an UNIQUE column named `txn_id` which has some kind of keys in it.

Comment: That column is not in your question?

Comment: Didn't know it was important. Updating.

Comment: is it possible to explain the use-case? i can't believe that this will cause no data mess if you find a solution? why updating rows, if you don't know which should be updated.

Comment: Ok, so you can uniquely identify a row, where do you want the array values to go? .. value 14 can go to user_id 5 and foo_unique or to bar_unique of 123_unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
    amount = 
        CASE id 
            WHEN 1 THEN 14
            WHEN 2 THEN 6
            WHEN 3 THEN 9
            ELSE amount -- just in case user_id 5 has records not covered above.
        END
WHERE 
    user_id = 5
```

Comment: @HopeIHelped, I think the point is to use CASE in such scenarios and this is just an example

Comment: But even using CASE is not the best solution - you need the explicit ID values which would require a subquery to retrieve.

Comment: When you say `not the best solution`, are you talking about performance? This update statement gives the desired effect of updating, provided those indexes on the array correspond to the values of `id` column for rows whose `user_id` is 5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, there is nothing on your array that says which array entry belongs to which database row. If you want to rely just on the orders (of the array indices, and the database `id`s,), you have to `SELECT` all rows for the user first, then loop and update a row at a time. Something like this on PHP (and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)):

```
$values = array(14, 6, 9);
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname', 'username', 'password');
$selectQuery = 'SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE user_id = 5 ORDER BY id';
foreach($dbh->query($selectQuery) as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE yourtable SET amount = :val WHERE id = :id");
    $sth->execute(array(
        'val' => array_unshift($values),
        'id' => $id
    ));
}
```

(Code above assumes the number of values on your arrays matches the number of database rows for `user_id = 5`).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem you only need to have SQL statements.

First is to **create two tables**:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
  user_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  username varchar(25),
) Engine = InnoDB;

CREATE table userbalances (
  balance_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11),
  amount decimal(10,2),
  CONSTRAINT userid_fk FOREIGN KEY userid_fk(user_id) REFERENCES users(userid)
) Engine = InnoDB;
```

Then, **after you have INSERT(ed)** all of the users and userbalances inside the table, all you need to do is **create an UPDATE statement** to update the amount:

```
UPDATE userbalances SET amount=? WHERE user_id=? AND balanceid=?
```

The **update should be in a loop**. And you should use **mysql_query()** function to update it with the assigned arrays that you have.

**Note:**
Both **userid** and **balanceid** should be in the WHERE clause of your UPDATE statement because you have **multiple transactions** inside the **userbalances** table. Otherwise, it's going to change all of the balances of all the transactions of that user.

**Problem update:**
If you don't use any SQL Cases on this problem, then your problem is just PHP. You need to find out what is the function for UPDATE(ing) - to update the amounts. As long as your tables are all prepopulated. There might be a function on the program you use to update it.